# Assigning a value to a tuple

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to assign the value of a variable `display_image` to a tuple `five_image` and return it via get_context_data method to a html page.

I know the below context.update is working as when I hard code the tuple via `five_image = "P5D5.jpg";` the correct value is returned on the page

The below print function is also working and prints the value of five_image to terminal.

So why do both parts together not work?

```
 class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      
        def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
            context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  

            if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']:

                display_image = random.choice(path_one_images)   

                if self.steps.current == '5':

                    five_image = ();
                    five_image = display_image 
                    print 'this is five_image', five_image

                context.update({'display_image': display_image,
                                'five_image': five_image,
                                 })

                path_one_images.remove(display_image)

            return context
```

Comment: This: `five_image = "P5D5.jpg"` assigns `five_image` to a `str`, not a `tuple`. What do you expect `five_image` and `display_image` to actually look like when this function is done?

Comment: I want five_image to take the value of display_image permanently

Comment: Having a variable with a permanent value that cannot be changed is not possible in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is dynamically typed. There's no such thing as a "tuple variable", there are only names. If you want a tuple to be assigned to a name, you need a tuple on the RHS of the assignment:

```
five_image = (display_image,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define tuple as we can define list

```
five_image = []
```

you must put tuple value in round paranthesis with comma if it's single value.

```
five_image  = (display_image,)
```

Hopefully it will work for you.